# Is it possible to pass closure into selector?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible in swift, passing a closure into selector?

for example, Is it possible to rewrite this code:

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneAction(_:)))
    
@objc func doneAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    self.myTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

to be:

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: { _ sender in 
    self.myTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
})
```

I've tried the above code and got:

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type 'Selector'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. If the parameter type is a selector, you must pass in a selector. Some classes offer both options, using different methods, but UIBarButtonItem is not one of them.

Comment: I found a workaround in:

https://medium.com/@BeauNouvelle/adding-a-closure-to-uibarbuttonitem-24dfc217fe72